# Javascript Google Chrome Console, log and functions preservation

Tags: javascript

I am working in the console of Google chrome trying to automate a procedure. It is a form and if the given data matches the data on the server, it gives you a result. If not, it redirects you to an error site were with a function again in the console you can go back to the original form.

I have written a basic program but when I get redirected (I have preserve log) the program I have written stops. Is there a wait to make a program that will continually interact with the site regardless of whether I get navigated to an other one? How can I make the Chrome console to continue sending instructions?